# Zend-Framework related

Tags: php, zend-framework

I got two zend forms which belongs to one table in the database,  broke it up in order to make sure the user does not find it lazy to finish it but I have a problem with my code in my model. I keep getting this error even though I tried numerous solutions.

Fatal error: Call to a member function save() on a non-object

```
public function smmedetailssmmedetails($companyname, $companytradingname)
{
    $data = array(              
        'companyname' => $companyname,
        'companytradingname' => $companytradingname,
    );
    return $this->insert($data);
} 

public function smmesdetails2smmedetails($smmeid, $numberemployees, $ownership)
{
    $row = $this->find($smmeid)->current();
    $row->numberemployees = $numberemployees;
    $row->ownership = $ownership;
    return $row->save(); //problem lies on this line
}
```

Tried using the following codes/methods

```
$this ->row->save();
$row->save();
$this ->row->save();
return $this -> row->save();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error you're getting, none of the method invocations you are trying will work.

You should first check what

```
$this->find($smmeid)->current();
```

returns using either a debugger, [var_dump](http://www.php.net/var_dump) or [print_r](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php).

In your case, it seems that either null or something that is not an object is returned.

Answer (score 1):

This means, that `$row` is not an object (should be), but probably is `null`. This means that `find()` method didn't get any result from database.

You should check `$smmeid` value and check if a such a row exists in the database.

Use `var_dump` function to check any variable in any line. This is how you can debug your problem.

Comment: $smmeid is the primary key, i slipt the forms each has its own controller, and by clicking next you go to the next form, I need so that the information will remain on the same row in the table

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys I got it using this method below, I marked codeblur answer because it was close thanks for the print_r information:

```
Example #1 print_r() example
<pre>
<?php
$a = array ('a' => 'apple', 'b' => 'banana', 'c' => array ('x', 'y', 'z'));
print_r ($a);
?>
</pre>
```

return ($row);//correct answer